# How to print Selected Datagridview Columns in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net programming. I'm finding it really hard printing selected columns in a datagridview. There are 12 columns and I would like to print just a few in a landscape view. Can someone help with related posts or articles?

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16670/DataGridView-Printing-by-Selecting-Columns-and-Row)

**Code:**

```
private static void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, 
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) 
{
    int tmpWidth, i;
    int tmpTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    int tmpLeft = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    int HeaderHeight=0;

    try 
    {            
        // Before starting first page, it saves
        // Width & Height of Headers and CoulmnType
        if (PageNo == 1) 
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dgv.Columns)
            {
                if (!GridCol.Visible) continue;
                // Skip if the current column not selected
                if (!PrintDGV.SelectedColumns.Contains(
                     GridCol.HeaderText)) continue;

                // Detemining whether the columns
                // are fitted to the page or not.
                if (FitToPageWidth) 
                    tmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)(
                               (double)GridCol.Width / 
                               (double)TotalWidth * (double)TotalWidth * 
                               ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / 
                                (double)TotalWidth))));
                else
                    tmpWidth = GridCol.Width;

                HeaderHeight = 
                   (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                    GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, tmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                // Save width & height of headres and ColumnType
                ColumnLefts.Add(tmpLeft);
                ColumnWidths.Add(tmpWidth);
                ColumnTypes.Add(GridCol.GetType());
                tmpLeft += tmpWidth;
            }
        }

        // Printing Current Page, Row by Row
        while (RowPos <= dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow GridRow = dgv.Rows[RowPos];
            if (GridRow.IsNewRow || (!PrintAllRows && !GridRow.Selected))
            {
                RowPos++;
                continue;
            }

            CellHeight = GridRow.Height;

            if (tmpTop + CellHeight >= 
                 e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
            {
                DrawFooter(e, RowsPerPage);
                NewPage = true;
                PageNo++;
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (NewPage)
                {
                    // Draw Print Title
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintTitle, 
                           new Font(dgv.Font, FontStyle.Bold), 
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, 
                            e.MarginBounds.Top -
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString(PrintTitle, 
                            new Font(dgv.Font, 
                            FontStyle.Bold), 
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    String s = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + 
                               DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                    // Draw Time and Date    
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(s, 
                            new Font(dgv.Font, FontStyle.Bold), 
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + 
                            (e.MarginBounds.Width - 
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, new Font(dgv.Font, 
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), 
                            e.MarginBounds.Top - 
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString(PrintTitle, 
                            new Font(new Font(dgv.Font, 
                            FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), 
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    // Draw Headers
                    tmpTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                    i = 0;
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dgv.Columns)
                    {
                        if (!GridCol.Visible) continue;
                        if (!PrintDGV.SelectedColumns.Contains(
                                            GridCol.HeaderText)) 
                            continue;

                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new 
                            SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), 
                            new Rectangle((int) ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop,
                            (int)ColumnWidths[i], HeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 
                            new Rectangle((int) ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop,
                            (int)ColumnWidths[i], HeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, 
                            GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, 
                            new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop, 
                            (int)ColumnWidths[i], HeaderHeight), StrFormat);
                        i++;
                    }
                    NewPage = false;
                    tmpTop += HeaderHeight;
                }

                // Draw Columns Contents
                i = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (!Cel.OwningColumn.Visible) continue;
                    if (!SelectedColumns.Contains(
                            Cel.OwningColumn.HeaderText))
                        continue;

                    // For the TextBox Column
                    if (((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                         "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn" || 
                        ((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                         "DataGridViewLinkColumn")
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), 
                                Cel.InheritedStyle.Font, 
                                new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)ColumnLefts[i], 
                                (float)tmpTop,
                                (int)ColumnWidths[i], 
                                (float)CellHeight), StrFormat);
                    }
                    // For the Button Column
                    else if (((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                                     "DataGridViewButtonColumn")
                    {
                        CellButton.Text = Cel.Value.ToString();
                        CellButton.Size = new Size((int)ColumnWidths[i], 
                                                    CellHeight);
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(CellButton.Width, 
                                                CellButton.Height);
                        CellButton.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 
                          new Point((int)ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop));
                    }
                    // For the CheckBox Column
                    else if (((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                              "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn")
                    {
                        CellCheckBox.Size = new Size(14, 14);
                        CellCheckBox.Checked = (bool)Cel.Value;
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)ColumnWidths[i], 
                                                 CellHeight);
                        Graphics tmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                        tmpGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 
                                new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                        CellCheckBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, 
                                new Rectangle((int)((bmp.Width - 
                                CellCheckBox.Width) / 2), 
                                (int)((bmp.Height - CellCheckBox.Height) / 2), 
                                CellCheckBox.Width, CellCheckBox.Height));
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 
                                new Point((int)ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop));
                    }
                    // For the ComboBox Column
                    else if (((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                              "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn")
                    {
                        CellComboBox.Size = new Size((int)ColumnWidths[i], 
                                                CellHeight);
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(CellComboBox.Width, 
                                                CellComboBox.Height);
                        CellComboBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 
                                new Point((int)ColumnLefts[i], tmpTop));
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), 
                                Cel.InheritedStyle.Font, 
                                new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), 
                                new RectangleF((int)ColumnLefts[i] + 1, 
                                tmpTop, (int)ColumnWidths[i]
                                - 16, CellHeight), StrFormatComboBox);
                    }
                    // For the Image Column
                    else if (((Type) ColumnTypes[i]).Name == 
                              "DataGridViewImageColumn")
                    {
                        Rectangle CelSize = new Rectangle((int)ColumnLefts[i], 
                                tmpTop, (int)ColumnWidths[i], CellHeight);
                        Size ImgSize = ((Image)(Cel.FormattedValue)).Size;
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)Cel.FormattedValue, 
                                new Rectangle((int)ColumnLefts[i] + 
                                (int)((CelSize.Width - ImgSize.Width) / 2), 
                                tmpTop + (int)((CelSize.Height - 
                                ImgSize.Height) / 2), 
                                ((Image)(Cel.FormattedValue)).Width, 
                                ((Image)(Cel.FormattedValue)).Height));

                    }

                    // Drawing Cells Borders 
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 
                            new Rectangle((int)ColumnLefts[i], 
                            tmpTop, (int)ColumnWidths[i], CellHeight));

                    i++;

                }
                tmpTop += CellHeight;
            }

            RowPos++;
            // For the first page it calculates Rows per Page
            if (PageNo == 1) RowsPerPage++;
        }

        if (RowsPerPage == 0) return;

        // Write Footer (Page Number)
        DrawFooter(e, RowsPerPage);

        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Also refer below links:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/540b51be-b1d5-4877-87bb-35e90fd95493/printing-a-datagridview-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16601/Printing-Selected-Columns-and-Rows-in-a-DataGrid

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/datagridview-printing-by-user-selecting-rows-and-columns

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?523396-RESOLVED-Printing-a-Datagridview-Rows